# Remove white space above nav bar

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the white space above this navbar that I created?

http://gyazo.com/b41271cad8d41c08c52ff26b1f1cab9e

I have search StackOveflow for this answer, but can't find one that seems to fix my issue. I have set html, body padding/margin to 0 as well as reset all other elements. Does anyone have any advice?

```
<nav id="header">
  <div class="home-header">
    <a href="#"><h1> testing this </h1></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS

```
#header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: $main-color;
}
```

Comment: Did you try **top:0** ?

Comment: Any inner ellement has margin?

Comment: Have you set the margin and padding on your html and body element to zero?

Comment: Just add `h1` after `#header`(`#header h1`)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was the h1 tag in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GEUH/)

The space at the top is create by the `h1` because of its default margin. To fix this:

```
#header h1{
    margin:0px;
}
```

PS: I assume that you removed the margin for the body tag. If not here's how you remove it:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Ah this was the fix! Thanks so much. I didn't realize that h1 tag created margin.

Comment: @kevin yup, h1 creates a default margin. And check the update for the body tag. If you haven't set the margin to zero for the body, it will still create a white space. So in case you didn't remove the margin for the body tag, I added the code for it ;) If you don't have any more questions please mark it solved

Comment: My solution was to add Body margin = -50px in _layouts. Drove me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: $main-color;
}
body{
margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav id="header">
  <div class="home-header">
    <a href="#"><h1> testing this </h1></a>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Put The `body` Tag `margin:0px;` Header `margin:0px;` Try This Code

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. No other solution helped me, so eventually, I found one:

When I was coding the HTML file with Visual Studio in Windows, it saved it as UTF-8 BOM, so when the browser was rendering the page, it was misinterpreting that Byte Order Mark and showing it as a blank space above everything else.

If that is your case, you just need to reencode the file to UTF-8. I used Notepad++ for simplicity, but I'm almost sure you can do that inside VS as well.